# Correlation coefficient - Sum of squared errors bigger than sum of squared totals?

Tags: regression, correlation, matlab

I'm a total beginner in regression analysis. I've read about the correlation coefficient and I tried to implement it in MatLab like this:

```
function [r] = generalCorrelationCoef(measuredVals, fittedVals)
    mMean = mean(measuredVals);

    % Sum of squared errors
    SSE = sum((measuredVals - fittedVals).^2);

    % Sum of squared totals
    SST = sum((measuredVals - mMean).^2);

    % Correlation coefficient
    r = sqrt(1 - SSE/SST);
end
```

But when I have measured data

```
m = [
    0.5608
    0.8522
    0.9075
    0.9994
    0.8668
    0.7162
    0.9143]
```

and fitted data

```
f = [
    0.6390
    0.8005
    1.0865
    1.5326
    2.1743
    3.0472
    4.1869]
```

Then $SSE = 18.1779$ and $SST = 0.1291$, so $SSE > SST$ and that's nonsense.

So, what am I doing wrong here? Is the fit simply too bad to compute the correlation coefficient?

Comment: This can happen with misspecified models. Review this site for several similar threads. Be careful to avoid making this an exact duplicate to another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify a bit more on Michael's comment:

It seems that the fitted values increased in a quadratic like manner, a pattern that (at least at first sight) is absent in the measured data. This does indeed hint of a misspecified model.

In addition the negative values reported are due to the definition of the correlation coefficient used. For example if we used the definition of the correlation coefficient between two variables as their scaled covariance (`cov([m,f]) / (std(m)*std(f))`) we would get the same correlation coefficient as if using the function `corr` directly (`corr(m,f)` or `0.2281`).
The definition used in this post is the one that is particular to the case of using *univariate* linear least squares (which looking at the fitted values I suspect that this is not the case), so maybe it is just a case of using a definition incompatible with the experimental settings at hand.